# How to reload all spring beans?

Tags: spring, tomcat, reload, spring-profiles

I have a Spring application, some beans are for demo purpose, other for production and I choose one or other with @Profile annotation.
I add "demo" or "production" profile setting based on a database value.
I would like to reload all beans runtime with new profiles if use change this database value. I know how to get this event, but how to reload all beans based on new current profile settings?
For now I have to forse the user to manually reboot the container (Tomcat).

Comment: You are walking on the danger zone but some application context implementation have a refresh method. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#refresh--

Comment: Ok, but what do you suggest? Manual reload? Keep the same bean for demo and for production?

Comment: My recommendation is to avoid reloading at run time, there are many caveats to consider. An alternative would be loading both beans (prod and demo), make then implement a common interface and choose which one to use at run time, clearly this depends on your current architecture and it is hard to present a sound recommendation without understand your needs in detail.

Comment: Thanks @Rafa maybe I should completely reload the container, but I cannot do it from inside Tomcat. I will consider to load both implementations in a common bean.